# LWC download shows 'errorduringprocessing.jsp'

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, contentversion, customer-portal

On our customer portal, we provide the option to download `ContentVersion` from Salesforce using the following endpoint: `/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/{ContentVersionId}`. And we open it with `window.open(link, '_blank')`, so the link is opened in a new tab. The portal url is a custom domain.

The download usually works, and I personally haven't been able to reproduce it. However, some of the users have let us know that sometimes they're seeing a blank page with the error message: `top.location='https://<portal_url>/ex/errorduringprocessing.jsp'` the first time they try to download.

The download seems to work when they try a second time from my understanding, so I thought this could be caused by timeouts or some session issue. I increased the timeout for the community profiles we have, but that doesn't seem to have helped at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I can't seem to find a solution anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be happening on experience cloud sites with custom domain setup. If a user manages to login to the portal using the default domain (ending with xxx.force.com), the download links seem to be broken, at least in our case.

I decided to look deeper into the login histories of the affected users and found out that they use the default portal URL to login (which was delivered via email when their case was updated).

Example:

1. The user receives an email that their case has been updated. They
   click the link and get to `https://<orgname>.force.com/portalname/s/`
   and login here.
2. The user can navigate the portal without issues, however when they
   click the download link, they get redirected to `https://<portal_url>.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/{ContentVersionId}` instead of staying on the force.com domain.
3. Since the user was seemingly never authenticated on `https://<portal_url>.com`, Salesforce denies them access to the `ContentVersion`

Workaround for this is to always force the user to login on the custom portal domain, and not let them login using the force.com domain. Maybe a forced redirect can be implemented before they can even login.

Strangely, `https://<orgname>.force.com` redirects the users to `https://<portal_url>.com` but `https://<orgname>.force.com/portalname` doesn't redirect users.

Answer (score -3):

Uncheck salesforce files options in Connected apps Access in profiles.

Uncheck  Select Files from Salesforce options from Administrative Permissions in profiles.

Comment: I don't see how does this would solve the problem. Seems like it would disable downloads (and Files in its entirety) for users. It's important that you read and understand the question being asked before trying to answer it.